# Spring boot failed on build with SQLiteDialect, when db file has already exist

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, jpa, spring-boot

When I try building spring boot project, got following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No add column syntax supported by org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getAddColumnString(Dialect.java:2088) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlAlterStrings(Table.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.migrateTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
... 76 common frames omitted
```

There is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:test.db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

there are dependencies from `build.gradle` that i use

```
dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
  compile 'com.zsoltfabok:sqlite-dialect:1.0'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final'
```

When `test.db` file is not exist, project has built successful.

When I tried to use MySQL(database/dialect/dependecies) everything is works without execptions and problems.

Maybe someone know how to handle this one?

Thanks to ALL!

Comment: Looks like your JPA provider does not support `ADD COLUMN` syntax with SQLite (look at its LOG and see what is being attempted). Other JPA providers do support such things, and SQLite has syntax for that

Comment: Try using `compile group: 'com.enigmabridge', name: 'hibernate4-sqlite-dialect', version: '0.1.2'` instead of `com.zsoltfabok:sqlite-dialect:1.0`

Comment: downgrade *hibernate version* and changing *sqlite-dialect provider* was helpful for me! 

`compile 'com.github.gwenn:sqlite-dialect:master'
+    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'`

Thanks to All